# Geo: intent with a placeid

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to make a button to launch google maps on a device and open to a specific place [not just a lat/lon, although that is the fallback].

I have a place id, and want to launch a geo: intent to the place.  I can't seem to find the uri structure I need to do that - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this question is old, but it is still a current problem, which isn't until today not implemented by Google. There is no direct URI for that, but I've solved it via the `q` parameter. First I send the name of the place and then the address. For me it works pretty well.

```
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + place.getName() + ", " + place.getAddress());
 Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
 mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
 startActivity(mapIntent);
```

If you don't have the address and the name, you can look up this via the [Places API Webservice](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

Comment: This is the best answer so far, so, I'm marking it.

Comment: @Namingwaysway Thank you very much!